# How to debug website running on Firefox (iOS)?

Tags: javascript, ios, debugging, firefox

I am looking for an equivalent to remote debugging using Safari to debug a JavaScript edge case that only occurs on Firefox (iOS).

For this project, a remote console would be enough.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use Firefox PC and use the mobile emulator in debugging tools

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but I believe this wouldn't work given Firefox on iOS runs WebKit.

Comment: Has anyone had any luck seeing JS errors in Firefox for iOS using any methods? My site sees an uncaught "Script error", and it's impossible to get any more details because Firefox for iOS doesn't expose any kind of console.

Comment: Perhaps https://inspect.dev would work but it’s not free

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone else comes across this post remote debugging on a mac in safari dev tools works for ios firefox as well