# Debug Firefox on iOS Javascript errors

Tags: javascript, ios, firefox

I have a Javascript error that occurs only on Firefox on iOS (not even also on iPad). I can reproduce the fault, but it is impossible to get any more information about it. onerror redacts all the content in the error event because it is crossorigin (adding crossorigin="anonymous" to the script element doesn't help, unlike in other browsers).

So while that's how I know it is happening, I have no idea where. I have tried putting alerts everywhere: that also hasn't isolated it, and the error seems to have no adverse effects at all on my code, so I am starting to think this may be an error in Firefox's own scripts, maybe that I am somehow triggering, or that often happens but only seen because I have an error handler. But I'd like to be sure that I don't have a bug or compatibility issue with iOS FF somewhere.

In theory, as iOS Firefox is running Webkit, I should be able to run the developer tools in Safari on a Mac and debug remotely over USB. A number of places tell me I can do that, including this:
[How to debug website running on Firefox (iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802698/how-to-debug-website-running-on-firefox-ios)

But it doesn't work for me. I can debug iOS *Safari* OK with that method, so both ends are set up correctly, but all I see is 'No inspectable applications' when I'm using *Firefox* on the iPhone.

Perhaps it used to work in earlier versions. I'm using latest iOS16.4, and Safari 16.4.1 on Mac (which I can't upgrade beyond macOS Monterey, so is the latest I can get) (and in Safari Technology Preview).

Any thoughts on what I could do next. (Buying a more recent Mac just to see if MacOS Ventura works is not an option, and as I can debug iOS Safari, that seems unlikely anyway).

Comment: Seems impossible as of May 2023. This seemed promising https://wiki.mozilla.org/CloudServices/Sync/File_an_iOS_bug -- in Firefox iOS, open Settings, tap version number 5 times, see new debug options, including "Debug: copy log files to app container". But those log files don't have anything useful, not even browser console messages.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say his is happening to me too. I also can't debug it for the same reasons.

This is definitely an issue with either Apple or Mozilla to fix as scripts do load and run fine.

For now I have done this:

```html
  window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, col, error) {
    let err = "A fatal exception has occurred. The application will now reload.\nException details -> " + msg + "\nUrl: " + url + "\nLine: " + line + '\nColumn: ' + col + '\nError: ' + error;
    console.error(err);
    if (!(navigator.userAgent.match("FxiOS") && msg === "Script error.")) {
      alert(err);
      location.reload();
    }
    return true;
  }
```